# The archive with all the LaTeX material as a camera ready version

Tags: conference, paper-submission

This happened to me for the first time. The organizers of the conference asked everyone to send them the archive with all the LaTeX material as a camera ready version of an accepted paper.

Is this a legitimate request?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what exactly you're asking.  You've submitted a paper for publication and the conference accepted the paper and now they're asking you to submit the paper in LaTeX format.  This is all very standard.  What's your concern here?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, yes, exactly, so I will send the LaTeX material.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I don't normally publish in CS-style conferences, but I have always thought that "camera-ready" meant "give us the pdf", and [Wikipedia confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera-ready). Is it not the case in your field? So I, like OP, find this request unusual.

Comment: This means- "we're not going to copy edit your paper, and you must use our standard document class in your paper.  We'll run it through LaTeX and adjust page numbers to fit it into the proceedings volume."

Answer (score 2):

I've notice this becoming increasingly common in CS. It's annoying, but if the conference is well known, it shouldn't be an issue.